# C++ equivalent of Java StringUtils.indexOfDifference

Tags: c++, string-comparison

For C++20, is there a library equivalent of Java's [`StringUtils.indexOfDifference()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#indexOfDifference(java.lang.String%5B%5D))?

What is the efficient way of comparing two large strings and determining where they differ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) from `<algorithm>`

> Returns the first mismatching pair of elements from two ranges

For example

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>

std::size_t IndexOfDifference(std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs) {
    auto diff = std::mismatch(lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin());
    return std::distance(lhs.begin(), diff.first);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << IndexOfDifference("foobar", "foocar");
}
```

Will [output](https://godbolt.org/z/jdPvWe6re)

```
3
```

Comment: oh, I missed that OP only wants the index. This is of course much simpler than mine

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`std::mismatch`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/mismatch) if you take care about the different cases that lead to an end iterator in the result:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

void mism(const std::string& a, const std::string& b){
    auto its = std::mismatch(a.begin(), std::next(a.begin(),std::min(a.size(),b.size())),b.begin());
    if (its.first == a.end() && its.second == b.end()) {
        std::cout << "the strings are equal\n";
    } else if (its.first != a.end() && its.second != b.end()){
        std::cout << "the strings differ at " << *(its.first) << " and " << *(its.second) << "\n";
    } else if (its.first == a.end()) {
        std::cout << "the second string starts with the first\n";
    } else if (its.second == b.end()) {
        std::cout << "the first string start with the second\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    mism("foo1abc","foo2abc");
    mism("foo","foo");
    mism("foo123","foo");
    mism("foo","foo123");

}
```